# keeping highlighted tab in navigation bars

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

thanks for your time.
I've been having a lot of trouble trying to highlighting the "active" tab on a navbar i am using. I'm trying to do this through CSS but the problem arises when I change pages. I will add the following code:


`function updateMenu(num)

{`

> var menuCode =
>
> > '`<ul id="menu">`' + 
> >     '`<li><a href="software/menu.php" onclick="updateMenu(1);"';` 
> >     `if(num == 1){menuCode +=' class="current"';}` 
> >  
> >     `menuCode += '>Software</a></li>'`+ 
> >     '`<li><a href="users/menu.php" onclick="updateMenu(2);"';` 
> >     `if(num == 2){menuCode +=' class="current"';}` 
> >  
> >     `menuCode += '>Software</a></li>';`

document.getElementById("cssMenu").innerHTML = menuCode;

}

And my list goes as follows:

> `<ul id="menu">`
>
> > `<li><a href="software/menu.php" onclick="updateMenu(1);">Software</a></li>`
> >     `<li><a href="user/menu.php" onclick="updateMenu(2);">Users</a></li>`
> >     `</ul>`

I feel it's an unelegant solution because of all the code wrote in the updateMenu function and i was wondering if there was a more elegant solution to my problem. (You can see it's on moving the "class=current" so the CSS works properly).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your exact requirement is. Assuming that on clicking the tab, it does NOT go to another page, the following code will help [please use [Jquery]](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js):

HTML :

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu li").click(function(){
    $("#menu li").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
 });
});
</script>
```

CSS :

```
.highlight {
 background: #f00;
}
```