# How do I keep active link color?

Tags: html, css

Here is the html of my basic nav bar:

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>               
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Location</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've created a fiddle to display my question:

http://jsfiddle.net/97L5srjf/2/

When hovering on an item in the dropdown menu, I want the original link in the nav bar to remain black instead of changing back to white. How do I select it to do this?

p.s. please disregard the white space in the dropdown of this fiddle. I'm not sure why it's there or how to get rid of it.

Comment: Hover li, make anchor black `#nav li:hover a { ... }` http://jsfiddle.net/97L5srjf/3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354983/keeping-highlighted-tab-in-navigation-bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
#nav li:hover a { color: #000; }
```

The above says, while the `li` is hovered, make the anchor tag colour black.

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/97L5srjf/3/

Comment: If someone can explain the down vote, that would be helpful as this solution is correct

Comment: I think the OP asks something really different: how to make that hover state persist. Also, your answer is what he already has. I guess that's why someone downvoted you, the answer is wrong and you're not paying attention to what the OP already has.

Comment: @Fabio no it is not what OP already have, if you compare his fiddle and my fiddle (hover the second item) you will see the difference. His fiddle, the second link is white while hovering on the sub item, mine it is black as OP has asked for

Comment: you're correct, I misunderstood that question myself. Here's my +1

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS:

```
#nav li:hover a
{
   color: #000;
}
```